# What is semantic of org.slf4j.Logger.isDebugEnabled(Marker)?

Tags: logback, slf4j

Slf4j has [boolean isDebugEnabled(Marker marker)](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html#isDebugEnabled(org.slf4j.Marker)) and Javadoc says nothing about `marker` argument.

Logback implementation [public boolean isDebugEnabled(org.slf4j.Marker marker)](https://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/Logger.html#isDebugEnabled(org.slf4j.Marker)) leads to:

```
public abstract FilterReply decide(
        Marker marker, Logger logger, Level level,
        String format, Object[] params, Throwable t);
```

Still I don't understand why we need `Marker` in `is...Enabled()` method.

Is it for filtering events not only by `Level` but also by specific `Marker`?